# How to bypass IPC mechanism in case client and server run in same process context in gRPC?

Tags: c++, grpc

In a project that I'm working on (on a linux based system), I have server, which can have multiple clients.All of this happens on a single machine, hence I'm using Unix Domain Sockets as grpc IPC mechanism.
Now, one of the clients runs in the same process context as the server. In this case, I want to be able to by-pass the IPC mechanism as it just adds overhead and is not required here. I'm developing this in C++. I see there's a mention of `inProcessChannel` [here](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server.html#ad48818dac08e28a2ea3694d1f5462c6b) in their documentation, but how do I actually create one and use it for my use-case? Looks like it's present only in `grpc::Server` namespace.

I was planning to let the client and server initially communicate via standard agreed upon USD gRPC channel, so that client can query server for it's PID and check against it's own PID, and if it match, I want to be able to use `inProcessChannel` to communicate (My understanding is that it will bypass any IPC overhead.

I was struck on how I can create an `inProcessChannel` from client side. I couldn't find any way to do is via `grpc::CreateChannel`. Does it mean I have to create it in server, and pass back the channel to the client and create a stub with that and communicate?

Could someone please give me some pointers?